# How to add extra text encodings to TextEdit on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, encoding, textedit

When saving a file as in TextEdit on Mac OS X 10.11 (El Capitan), you can choose a text encoding for the file. There are a few options and then at the bottom “Customise Encodings List…”

However, the encoding I want to choose is not in the list, even in the very long list. How I can add a new encoding to this list? The one I want to save a file in is the Windows-1252 encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) is one of the most common encodings out there. But it goes under different names at times such as CP-1252 and Windows Latin 1.

Looking at the “Plain Text Encoding” options when saving a file with TextEdit in Mac OS X 10.11.5 (El Capitan), you can see that “Western (Windows Latin 1)” is right there in that list. It would be strange if it wasn’t since—like I said—it’s so commonly used.

[image: Screenshot of the “Plain Text Encoding” options available in TextEdit.]